# Format XML in racket

Tags: xml, racket

I am working now with racket and XML creation files. To do so, I'm using the function:

```
(display-to-file
 ( SOME_XEXPR )
(FILE_PATH)
```

And the XML looks like one bit mess. No newlines, identation or whitespaces, only one long line. How do I make the output look nicer?

Comment: Use [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to post-process your XML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [xml module](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xml/index.html?q=xml); `display-xml` can be of help for example:

```
(require xml)
(display-xml (read-xml (open-input-string "<a>1<b>2</b></a>")))
```

yields

```
<a>
  1
  <b>
    2
  </b>
</a>
```

Comment: You'll have to be careful about reading it back in, though... you probably don't want lots of spaces and newlines in your xml representation.

Comment: @JohnClements True; the doc clearly says *"Like write-xml, but newlines and indentation make the output more readable, though less technically correct when whitespace is significant."*